# Getting Travel Distance and Travel Time from Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps API V3 to draw the walking route between 2 points `startPosition` and `endPosition` using `google.maps.DirectionService`. It should then print to console the route's distance and travel duration.

**Problem:** Although the code does draw the route successfully, it seems that `directionsDisplay.setDirections` lack a callback function to return the distance and travel time values to the caller.

Furthermore, adding a listener for `directions_changed` does not seem to work as well, the listener is not triggered!

Any ideas how I can pass the distance value and travel time values from `displayRoute()` to its caller?

```
displayRoute = function(startPosition, endPosition) {

    var start = startPosition
    var end = endPosition
    var map = GoogleMaps.maps.map.instance

    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({'map': map});
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(); 

    var request = {
        origin : start,
        destination : end,
        travelMode : google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response)
            // ... and triggers listener for 'directions_changed'
        }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
        console.log('directions_changed')    # not executed
        console.log(response.routes[0])      # not executed
        return response.routes[0]
    });


}



var route = displayRoute(startPos, endPos)
console.log(route.duration.value)    # undefined
console.log(route.distance.value)    # undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined because the code is, the distance and duration are properties of the leg object.
`console.log(response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value);`
`console.log(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);`